# How do i notify eclipse that an element was created

Tags: eclipse, view, editor

what is the standard way in eclipse to notify a view that an elment was added. In my cases i have one view in which items are created (tree viewer). Once that is done all other interrested parties shall be informed.

In another case all interrested views shall be informed if the data in an editor was changed. Should this be the save of an completly new object than this new item shall be added to a view.

What is the best way to do this without implmenting my own listener mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

In your viewer's content provider there is a method:

```
public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput);
```

According to the documentation:

> Notifies this content provider that the given viewer's input has been
>   switched to a different element.
>
> A typical use for this method is registering the content provider as a
>   listener to changes on the new input (using model-specific means), and
>   deregistering the viewer from the old input. In response to these
>   change notifications, the content provider should update the viewer
>   (see the add, remove, update and refresh methods on the viewers).

You can use this method to notify other classes that your input has changed. (i.e. - an element was added .. )